# regex: continuous numbering replace

Tags: regex, replace, numbers, notepad++

I have a text with the word 'article' repeated, I need using Notepad ++ to replace each of that word with a number, starting with '1', then the next instance '2'.. etc.  something like {\d+[+1]}

For example:

```
this is article and this is another article.  Here is an article etc.
```

becomes:

```
this is 1 and this is another 2.  Here is an 3 etc.
```

Comment: This cannot be done with notepad++.  However it could be done fairly easily with a programming language, sed, or awk.

Comment: I never used any of these..  can you suggest a way to do that and download the needed tools for Windows? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but this is tricky.
Assuming you don't have any # in your file, replace each line by the next one (replace all and multiple times):

```
(?<!#)(#*article)([^#]*?)((?=\1))
\1\2#\3
```

So this gives: `this is article and this is another #article.  Here is an ##article etc.`. Continue with:

```
article
\#
```

So you have:
`this is # and this is another ##.  Here is an ### etc.`

Now every article is mapped to n times the number of pounds of its position.  To convert to base 10, you need to perform the following operations alternatively and repeatingly (assuming that % does not appear in the original text)

```
#{10}
%

%{10}
#
```

And so on until you cannot replace neither the first nor the second. Then you can do:

```
(#|%)\1{8}
9

(#|%)\1{7}
8

(#|%)\1{6}
7

(#|%)\1{5}
6

(#|%)\1{4}
5

(#|%)\1{3}
4

(#|%)\1{2}
3

(#|%)\1{1}
2

(#|%)
1
```

And voilà! `this is 1 and this is another 2.  Here is an 3 etc.` If you have n articles in your document, The first operation takes O(n) times to click on "replace all", the second O(log(n)), the third O(1), so the total time is actually O(n) which is what you would have expected.